# How to gray out html table and display loader in the middle of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html table which display some data about persons. The last three columns are buttons to perform some actions on the wanted person.

The wanted behaviour is when a user clicks on one of the buttons to perform an actions on some user, the table grays out so that the user can't click on any of the other buttons and a loader displays on the middle of the table, until the Ajax reponse resolves, then the table back to it's normal.

My question here is how can we gray out the table so that the other buttons will be unclickable, and display a loader in the middle, using javascript.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:
You can wrap the table with position: relative element and fill the area with transparent div with loading spinner. It will prevent the user to click the buttons.

```js
function action() {
  var loader = document.querySelector("#loader");
  loader.classList.remove("hidden");
  fakeCall().then(function() {
    loader.classList.add("hidden");
  }).catch(function() {
    loader.classList.add("hidden");
  });
}

function fakeCall() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="loader hidden" id="loader"></div>
<table border="1" width="300" height="100">
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td><button onclick="action()">click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td><button onclick="action()">click</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```